# The context is not currently tracking the entity

Tags: c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

I am using [WCF DataService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the AutoMapper to Map the objects.

The below sample works fine when I get the single entity.

```
BOND contextBond = this.agent.Context.BONDS.Where(x => x.SECURITY_ID == Security.SECURITY_ID).FirstOrDefault();
Mapper.Map<BondItem, BOND>(this.Bond, contextBond);
this.agent.Context.UpdateObject(contextBond);
```

The below is the implementation for List Object. I am getting an exception *"The context is not currently tracking the entity."* at the last line

```
List<SECURITY_XREF> contextXREF = this.agent.Context.SECURITY_XREF.Where(x => x.SECURITY_ID == Security.SECURITY_ID).ToList();
Mapper.Map<List<SecurityXrefItem>, List<SECURITY_XREF>>(this.Xref, contextXREF);
this.agent.Context.UpdateObject(contextXREF);
```

Any Idea How can I resolve the issue? In other words how can I pass the List Objects to the UpdateObject Methods.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

The [DataServiceContext.UpdateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.updateobject%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) only accept single entity object, you have to call it once on each object in the list. [DataServiceContext.SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646716%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) will save all changes to server with one call.

```
foreach (var entity in list)
{
    context.UpdateObject(entity);
}
context.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: I did try that approach before and still got the same error msg "The context is not currently tracking the entity".

Answer (score 1):

```js
foreach (var entity in list)
{
    if(!context.IsAttached(entity)) context.Attach(entity);
    context.UpdateObject(entity);
}
context.SaveChanges()
```